# SSIS SQL "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data."

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Error# 1

> [OLE DB Source [1525]] Error: There was an error with output column
>   "ABC" (1545) on output "OLE DB Source Output" (1535). The column
>   status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a
>   potential loss of data.".

Error# 2

> [OLE DB Source [1525]] Error: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR. The "output column "ABC" (1545)"
>   failed because error code 0xC0209072 occurred, and the error row
>   disposition on "output column "ABC" (1545)" specifies failure on
>   error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified
>   component. There may be error messages posted before this with more
>   information about the failure.

Error# 3

> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED. The
>   PrimeOutput method on component "OLE DB Source" (1525) returned error
>   code 0xC0209029. The component returned a failure code when the
>   pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code
>   is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline
>   stopped executing. There may be error messages posted before this with
>   more information about the failure.

Comment: Nice errors. So what's the question?

Comment: @LukStorms,
my question is to get an answer for those errors

Comment: Seems similar to [this one](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/822634/SSIS-Error-The-value-could-not-be-converted-becaus). Are you trying to put too much text in a varchar that's to short for it?

Comment: @LukStorms to be clear: my file source is OLE DB and my destination is csv

Comment: A CSV? That's useful additional information to add to the question.  But I don't know anything about OLE DB, so I'm outta here.

Comment: What are the data types of column ABC? Data type of the Source. A and data type of the Output?

Comment: @TDP the data types of the source are varchar(25) and my destination is a csv file. I added a data conversion and added the DT_STR and size of 50 on the CSV editor, but still I am seeing the same error.

Comment: ABC in the database is probably > 25 characters? In the advanced editor on the Source you can tell it to ignore truncation errors. Might help you identify the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the Advanced Properties editor of your OLEDB Source, find the Output Column `ABC`, and change the length of it to something greater than the maximum possible length of the data of that column in the database.